# ConnectApi.Recommendations.getRecommendationForUser Error

Tags: apex

```
global  List<ConnectApi.RecommendationCollection> getRecom()
{
  List< ConnectApi.RecommendationCollection> recom =ConnectApi.Recommendations.getRecommendationForUser(null,'xxxxxxxxx00IbK8','follow','follow');
    return recom ;
}
```

I am trying to write code like above but getting error

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   ConnectApi.Recommendations.getRecommendationForUser(NULL, String,
>   String, String) at line 11 column 53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter has to be an Object ID (user ID, file ID, record Id, etc): 
 List values= ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType.values(); 
getRecommendationForUser(null,'xxxxxxxxx00IbK8',values[0],**'follow'**);

objectId

Type: String
Specifies the object to take action on.

- If action is follow, objectId is a user ID, file ID, or record ID.
- If action is join, objectId is a group ID.
- If action is view, objectId is a user ID, file ID, group ID, record ID, or custom recommendation ID (version 34.0 and later).

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: List<ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType> values= ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType.values(); 
'follow'=value[0]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was passing parameter as string for ConnectedApi.​RecommendationActionType as string it should be like

```
 List<ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType> values= ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType.values();
```

and pass the value as parameter like value[0] for follow...